# Label help for histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, histogram

I have a set of histograms and would like to put labels on the +- 1 stdev and the mean.  I have the lines, but want the labels as well.  I would like the labels toward the bottom of the histograms with white background so the font is legible against the histogram colors.

```
library(dply)
library(ggplot2)

a = runif(1000,1,100)
b = runif(1000,1,100)
c = runif(1000,1,100)

amount = c(a,b,c)

cat = c(rep("a",1000), rep("b",1000), rep("c",1000))

hist.data = data.frame(amount,cat)
names(hist.data) = c("amount","cat")

hist.data$cat = factor(hist.data$cat, levels = c("a","b","c"))
pricedata = ddply(hist.data, c("cat"), summarize, avg = mean(amount), minus.stdev = mean(amount)-sd(amount), 
  plus.stdev = mean(amount) + sd(amount))
pricedata = pricedata[order(pricedata$avg),]


ggplot(hist.data, aes(x=amount, fill = cat))+
  geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
  theme_test()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = avg), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = 1)+


  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+


  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = plus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+


  facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend converting your `pricedata` to long format - that somewhat simplifies your `geom_vline` calls (though you have to add `size` and `linetype` scales...) and makes using `geom_label` pretty simple. At this point, `geom_label` is pretty new, and doesn't allow you to do things like change the angle.

```
pricedata_long = tidyr::pivot_longer(pricedata, -cat)


ggplot(hist.data, aes(x=amount, fill = cat))+
  geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
  theme_test()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = value, linetype = name, size = name),
             data = pricedata_long, color = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(x = value, label = scales::dollar_format()(value)), data = pricedata_long,
             y = 0, fill = "white", vjust = -.1,
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c("avg" = 1, "minus.stdev" = 0.75, "plus.stdev" = 0.75)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("avg" = "solid", "minus.stdev" = "dotted", "plus.stdev" = "dotted")) +

  facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea for simplifying - however the labels are too large.  I researched the "label" geom and you can't resize it or modify it.  Any chance this can be done with geom_rect and geom_text?  I tried those but keep getting errors.

Comment: I mean, you can, but if it was easy `geom_label` would already do it. It's annoyingly difficult to know how big text will be for a given window size and make the box just a little bigger. But do try adjusting the `size` of the label - it can be a little clunky but it does work okay. Don't know where you read that you can't resize it.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to make the fewest changes to your existing code (although I agree the other answers are more elegant) you can add three lines to your existing

```r
ggplot(hist.data, aes(x=amount, fill = cat))+
  geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
  theme_test()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = avg), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = 1)+
  geom_label(aes(x = avg, y = 10, label = scales::dollar_format()(avg)), data = pricedata, fill = "white", size = 3) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
  geom_label(aes(x = minus.stdev, y = 10, label = scales::dollar_format()(minus.stdev)), data = pricedata, fill = "white", size = 3) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = plus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
  geom_label(aes(x = plus.stdev, y = 10, label = scales::dollar_format()(plus.stdev)), data = pricedata, fill = "white", size = 3) +
  facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))
```

[image]

Comment: Also a great solution - however the labels are too large.  I researched the "label" geom and you can't resize it or modify it.  Any chance this can be done with geom_rect and geom_text?  I tried those but keep getting errors.

Comment: You can add a size parameter to `geom_label` try ` size = 3` I changed it in the answer.

Comment: Will be happy to, but I don't know how to do that.  Guidance please.

Comment: LOL - To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.